# How do I use OCR in iPhone Notes?

Tags: iphone, notes.app

I was saving some hand-written note in iPhone Notes (suppose I had drawn "**hello world, how are you?**"). The default name suggested for the particular note was the start of the document ("**hello world**"). This suggested that Notes was able to convert handwriting to text, and comes with an OCR feature.

This was also strongly seconded when I included an image at the top of the note. The image was actually a screenshot of a browser page, and when I was trying to save it, the suggested name was the **URL** of the page, again indicating that OCR was performed.

However, I couldn't find how to convert handwritten notes/images to text in Notes, despite Notes supporting that. Is there any way to do it, or has this feature purposely been not provided?

PS - I know I can install third party apps to achieve the same. I just wondered how to do this using Notes.

Comment: What iOS version?

Comment: iOS version is `13.6`

Comment: If you have iPhone / iPad with A12 Bionic and later processor, it now has a [Live Text feature](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212630) that can read text. Apparently it supports handwriting.

Answer (score 1):

It’s done automatically as part of the document scanning feature.

[What’s New in Notes for iOS and iPadOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210552)

> **What else is new**
>
> - Use search to find text in documents, like receipts or bills, that you’ve scanned with the built in document scanner.
> - Search can also visually recognize images inside your notes such as images of a bike when you search for the word “bike.”

It’s just a built in function.  You may have to reimport the handwritten note do it’s processed by the OCR engine.

Comment: However, is it possible for me to copy the entire 'hand-written' thing in text format?

Comment: I just tested it and it will recognize handwriting (not very good though).  It will recognize handwriting from a new import.  Whether it's scanned in right there in notes or imported from photos.